# Is the ServletContext the preferred way to share resources among Servlets?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, jakarta-ee, shared

When I was looking for ways to share resources (e.g. a DataSource) between Servlets, most of the time using a ServletContextListener is proposed. Is this the standard way for sharing resources? Or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your requirement. You can, however, create a repository, for example a singleton object to keep your resources, of which object just one instance exists in whole JVM. Moreover, it's not a good practice to use servletcontext to get instances of resources for example data sources because of concurrency issues. For data resources i would use JNDI resources and let  container (tomcat or an application server) manage these resources, like any other service objects for instance DAOs. Spring solves these problems with an application context in which all service beans live. you need to define your service objects as beans in this context and  these can be injected (see dependency injection - CDI) in controllers, interceptors etc. where they are needed with different strategies.